# Union types integer and text cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql-12

After migrating database data from Postgresql 9 to GCP cloud sql PostgreSql 12, the query shown here is failing with this error:

> “UNION types integer and text cannot be matched”

Query:

```
Select c1, c2, c3 
From table t1 
Union all 
Select x_.* 
From 
    (Select c1, c2, c3 From table t2) as x_ 
Inner Join t3 as t on t.c33 = x_.c3 
Where c2 in (‘a’, ’b’, ’d’)
```

This type of query was working flawlessly in Postgresql 9, but is failing in Postgresql 12.

I'm not able to understand how to fix this issue.

Individually when I run both queries, the first part returns data but 2nd part of union all query is not returning any data

Comment: Can you please add the ddl statements for the three tables to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks a little bit complicated, try using:

```
Select c1,c2,c3 from table t1 
Union all 
select c1,c2,c3 from table t2 inner join t3 as t on t.c33=t2.c3 where c2 in ('a','b','d')
```

As per my understanding, the temp table which is created with `(select c1,c2,c3 from table t2) as x_` stores the newly created values as string, not as integer